# Sort an array in a strange format

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array as below:

```
Array
(
    [time] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6:00 PM
            [1] => 4:00 PM
        )

[id] => Array
    (
        [0] => #1 Hits of the 60's
        [1] => 3 Men and a Lady
    )

[url] => Array
    (
        [0] => hits-of-the-60
        [1] => 3-men-and-a-lady
    )

[ev_evc_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 2
    )

[address] => Array
    (
        [0] => Caravelle Theatre
        [1] => God and Country Theatre
    )

[phone] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1-800-4Branson (800-427-2676)
        [1] => 1-800-4Branson (800-427-2676)
    )

)
```

I want to sort the array based on time ascending.

Desired output is as below:

```
Array
(
    [time] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4:00 PM
            [1] => 6:00 PM
        )
[id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3 Men and a Lady
        [1] => #1 Hits of the 60's
    )

[url] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3-men-and-a-lady
        [1] => hits-of-the-60
    )

[ev_evc_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 2
    )

[address] => Array
    (
        [0] => God and Country Theatre
        [1] => Caravelle Theatre
    )

[phone] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1-800-4Branson (800-427-2676)
        [1] => 1-800-4Branson (800-427-2676)
    )

)
```

I have tried `asort, usort`. But could not make it work. Any help / suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I'm just assuming this, but it would be good to mention that the same key for each of the sub-arrays all describe the same item. So in other words `[time][0]` is corresponds to `[address][0]` and `[id][0]`. "Sorting by time" would mean swapping each of those other arrays as well. Which means that you would either need to sort each of those sub-arrays separately or transform the data structure to group them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), it will sort all arrays based on the first array given:

```
array_multisort(
    $myArray["time"],
    $myArray["id"],
    $myArray["url"],
    $myArray["ev_evc_id"],
    $myArray["address"],
    $myArray["phone"]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array is in the wrong order. Try if you can change it to this and usort will work

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [time] => 6:00 PM
            [id] => 1
            ...
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [time] => 4:00 PM
            [id] => 2
            ...
        )
)
```